# Change colour of text component during runtime based on the background colour of that component

Tags: c#, colors, runtime, unity-game-engine

I was wondering if it was possible to change the colour of a text component e.g. "Health", based on it's background colour during runtime. By background colour I don't mean the fixed background colour of the component as it has been created, I mean the actual colour located behind the text component itself. The goal of this would be to allow the text to contrast appropriately when positioned in-front of darker or lighter shades - ideally I only need the text to change colour to white or black depending on the background colour.

The only method I could imagine would be to attach a Collider2D component to the text, which calls an OnTriggerEnter2D method whenever a darker shade is detected. To achieve this I thought of assigning tags to those scene layers that require the adjustment to achieve a more suitable level of contrast. I've attached my proposed solution below, although due to it's nature of Collision I don't think it's feasible, I would welcome any suggestions. Thanks.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collide){
    if(collide.gameObject.tag == "ColourContrast"){
        hpText.color = new Color (1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean its definitely possible, but if you want a cheap and easy solution you could just make the text white with a black outline, as I'm sure you know this works over the top of any color.

Unity has a component for text outlines.

Comment: much less hassle than anything I was thinking of, this'll work great cheers!